# Merging two JSON arrays in Python using common value

Tags: python, json

I would like to ask your help with the following issue:
I have two JSON files generated from API calls which should be combinated using an unique value which is the serial number.
First JSON file which is a thousand line network device uplink list repeated in the following syntax:

```
{
    "serial": "ABCD-ABCD-ABCD",
    "model": "XYZ",
    "uplinks": [
        {
            "interface": "wan1",
            "status": "active",
            "ip": "10.10.10.2",
            "gateway": "10.10.10.2",
            "primaryDns": "8.8.8.8",
            "secondaryDns": "8.8.4.4",
            "ipAssignedBy": "dhcp"
        },
        {
            "interface": "wan2",
            "status": "not connected",
            "ip": "10.20.10.2",
            "gateway": "10.20.10.2",
            "primaryDns": "8.8.8.8",
            "secondaryDns": "8.8.4.4",
            "ipAssignedBy": "dhcp"
        }
    ]
}
```

Second JSON file which is a thousand line device inventory list repeated in the following syntax:

```
 {
   "name": "ABC",
   "serial": "ABCD-ABCD-ABCD",
   "mac": "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF",
   "networkId": "12412345235342",
   "productType": "appliance",
   "lanIp": "10.10.10.2",
   "configurationUpdatedAt": "2022-01-30T17:26:07Z",
   "url": "https://xyz"
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to insert the JSON 1 "uplinks" part into the JSON2 using the serial number as a matching value:

```
{
"name": "ABC",
"serial": "ABCD-ABCD-ABCD",
"mac": "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF",
"networkId": "12412345235342",
"productType": "appliance",
"lanIp": "10.10.10.2",
"configurationUpdatedAt": "2022-01-30T17:26:07Z",
"url": "https://xyz",
"uplinks": [
        {
            "interface": "wan1",
            "status": "active",
            "ip": "10.10.10.2",
            "gateway": "10.10.10.2",
            "primaryDns": "8.8.8.8",
            "secondaryDns": "8.8.4.4",
            "ipAssignedBy": "dhcp"
        },
        {
            "interface": "wan2",
            "status": "not connected",
            "ip": "10.20.10.2",
            "gateway": "10.20.10.2",
            "primaryDns": "8.8.8.8",
            "secondaryDns": "8.8.4.4",
            "ipAssignedBy": "dhcp"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json1={
    "serial": "ABCD-ABCD-ABCD",
    "model": "XYZ",
    "uplinks": [
        {
            "interface": "wan1",
            "status": "active",
            "ip": "10.10.10.2",
            "gateway": "10.10.10.2",
            "primaryDns": "8.8.8.8",
            "secondaryDns": "8.8.4.4",
            "ipAssignedBy": "dhcp"
        },
        {
            "interface": "wan2",
            "status": "not connected",
            "ip": "10.20.10.2",
            "gateway": "10.20.10.2",
            "primaryDns": "8.8.8.8",
            "secondaryDns": "8.8.4.4",
            "ipAssignedBy": "dhcp"
        }
    ]
}

json2= {
   "name": "ABC",
   "serial": "ABCD-ABCD-ABCD",
   "mac": "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF",
   "networkId": "12412345235342",
   "productType": "appliance",
   "lanIp": "10.10.10.2",
   "configurationUpdatedAt": "2022-01-30T17:26:07Z",
   "url": "https://xyz"
}
if json1['serial']==json2['serial']:
    json2['uplinks']=json1['uplinks']
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: It seems to be a fine approach, but I have two JSON files. I have to read them, merge by the serial as above, and save them back. Do you know what would be the best approach?
Thank you!

Comment: can you explain where do you want to save it back ? Like save it as a csv or need a response back as json ?

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing a bit :) I want to write the merged json to a .json file at the end.

Comment: with open('merged_json.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(json2, json_file)
By using the above code, you'll be able to save the json2 file which has all the content by the name of merged_json.